# Properly escaping output from command substitution to be used as arguments for another command

Tags: bash

Is there a way in bash that we can properly use the output of command substitution (` `COMMAND` ` or `$(COMMAND)`) as arguments for another program?

Example:

```
% touch -- safe-name -name-with-dash-prefix "name with space" \
    'name-with-double-quote"' "name-with-single-quote'" \
    'name-with-backslash\'
```

Neither this:

```
% ls -l `ls`
% ls -l $(ls)
```

nor this:

```
% ls -l "`ls`"
% ls -l "$(ls)"
```

can properly re-feed the output of the command substitution as arguments, for all the sample names. Without double quote, names with quotes are okay but not names with spaces. With double quote, name with spaces is okay but multiple names are joined together.

Note: please limit discussion to command subtitution (i.e. no pipes, mapfile, or xargs).

Comment: I set the IFS to newline in this case to handle most cases (but not file names with a newline)

Comment: @Philippos: that handles wordsplitting (except newline as you say) but not globbing so also do `set -f` or equivalent

Comment: Yes, but I see no globbing here